# Search text from bag of words in python

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing, text-parsing

Let's say I have a bag of keywords.
Ex :

```
['profit low', 'loss increased', 'profit lowered']
```

I have a pdf document and I parse the entire text from that, 
now I want to get the sentences which match the bag of words.

Lets say one sentence is :

```
'The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.'
```

This should match as in bag of words `'profit lowered'` matches this sentence.

What will be the best approach to solve this problem in python?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check all your **Check Words** list elements if it is inside the long sentence

```
sentence = 'The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.'

words = ['profit','month','5%']

for element in words:
    if element in sentence:
        #do something with it
        print(element)
```

If you want to go cleaner, you can use this one liner loop to collect the matched words to a list:

```
sentence = 'The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.'

words = ['profit','month','5%']

matched_words = [] # Will collect the matched words in the next life loop:

[matched_words.append(word) for word in words if word in sentence]

print(matched_words)
```

If you have "spaced" words on each element if your list, you want to take care of it by using the **split()** method.

```
sentence = 'The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.'

words = ['profit low','month high','5% 3%']

single_words = []
for w in words:
    for s in range(len(w.split(' '))):
        single_words.append(w.split(' ')[s])

matched_words = [] # Will collect the matched words in the next life loop:
[matched_words.append(word) for word in single_words if word in sentence]

print(matched_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# input
checking_words = ['profit low', 'loss increased', 'profit lowered']
checking_string = 'The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.'

trans_check_words = checking_string.split()
# output
for word_bug in [st.split() for st in checking_words]:
    if word_bug[0] in trans_check_words and word_bug[1] in trans_check_words:
        print(word_bug)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like the following:

convert the bag of words to a sentence:

```
bag_of_words = ['profit low', 'loss increased', 'profit lowered']    
bag_of_word_sent =  ' '.join(bag_of_words)
```

then with the list of sentences:

```
list_sents = ['The profit in the month of November lowered from 5% to 3%.']
```

use Levenshtein distance:

```
import distance
for sent in list_sents:
    dist = distance.levenshtein(bag_of_word_sent, sent)
    if dist > len(bag_of_word_sent):
        # do something
        print(dist)
```